# Python PIL, Image. Error after image.load()

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to load my .jpg file and it raises error, but if I try it again, it's ok! Why??

My code and error:

```
>>> import Image
>>> im1 = Image.open('/tmp/test.jpg')
>>> im1.load()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 201, in load
raise IOError("image file is truncated (%d bytes not processed)" % len(b))
IOError: image file is truncated (0 bytes not processed)
>>> im1.load()
<PixelAccess object at 0x7feffc2a1170>
>>>
```

Thank you!

Comment: The message suggests the image you're tying to load is (probably) missing some trailing bytes. Why does it work intermitently, I don't know, as you don't say if the image is static, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!  The image is static.

Answer (score 21):

I had this same issue and came up with a solution which I discuss here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23575424/3622198.

Somewhere before your code block, simply add the following:

```
from PIL import ImageFile
ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True
```

... and you should be good to go!

EDIT: It looks like this helps for the version of PIL bundled with Pillow ("pip install pillow"), but may not work for default installations of PIL

Answer (score 8):

PIL uses lazy loading, which means the image isn't actually read from the file until you try to perform an action on it. The first call to `load` is that first action, so that's when the problem with the file format is detected. The second call to `load` doesn't read the file again, it just returns information that was cached when the file was loaded.

Comment: Heh... Only now I noticed that the second call to `load` mentioned by OP was in the example...

Comment: Hm, sorry, I haven't told that the similar error happens when the first call is image.show. A second call image.show is ок.

Comment: @Hare, the same reasoning applies. The `open` request doesn't read the entire file so it doesn't get the error. The first operation whether it's `load` or `show` causes the entire file to be read, and the file defect is detected.