# PIL "IOError: image file truncated" with big images

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, zope

I think this problem is not Zope-related. Nonetheless I'll explain what I'm trying to do:

I'm using a PUT_factory in Zope to upload images to the ZODB per FTP. The uploaded image is saved as a Zope Image inside a newly created container object. This works fine, but I want to resize the image if it exceeds a certain size (width and height). So I'm using the thumbnail function of PIL to resize them i.e. to 200x200. This works fine as long as the uploaded images are relatively small. I didn't check out the exact limit, but 976x1296px is still ok.

With bigger pictures I get:

```
Module PIL.Image, line 1559, in thumbnail
Module PIL.ImageFile, line 201, in load
IOError: image file is truncated (nn bytes not processed).
```

I tested a lot of jpegs from my camera. I don't think they are all truncated.

Here is my code:

```
if img and img.meta_type == 'Image':
  pilImg = PIL.Image.open( StringIO(str(img.data)) )
elif imgData:
  pilImg = PIL.Image.open( StringIO(imgData) )

pilImg.thumbnail((width, height), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

As I'm using a PUT_factory, I don't have a file object, I'm using either the raw data from the factory or a previously created (Zope) Image object.

I've heard that PIL handles image data differently when a certain size is exceeded, but I don't know how to adjust my code. Or is it related to PIL's lazy loading?

Answer (score 266, accepted):

I'm a little late to reply here, but I ran into a similar problem and I wanted to share my solution. First, here's a pretty typical stack trace for this problem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File ..., line 2064, in ...
    im.thumbnail(DEFAULT_THUMBNAIL_SIZE, Image.ANTIALIAS)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1572, in thumbnail
    self.load()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 220, in load
    raise IOError("image file is truncated (%d bytes not processed)" % len(b))
IOError: image file is truncated (57 bytes not processed)
```

If we look around line 220 (in your case line 201—perhaps you are running a slightly different version), we see that PIL is reading in blocks of the file and that it expects that the blocks are going to be of a certain size. It turns out that you can ask PIL to be tolerant of files that are truncated (missing some file from the block) by changing a setting.

Somewhere before your code block, simply add the following:

```
from PIL import ImageFile
ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True
```

...and you should be good.

EDIT: It looks like this helps for the version of PIL bundled with Pillow ("pip install pillow"), but may not work for default installations of PIL

Comment: just out of curiosity, will this affect parsed image somehow? PIL will be quiet about truncated images, but will image be all right? I'd like to solve my problem but I wouldn't like to get corrupted images.

Comment: Pawel, the image will be completed to full size with gray color.

Comment: This works but it leaves an unsightly white bar on the bottom of my image. How can I dynamically crop this white bar off?

Comment: When I tried this in the python REPL, there was no problems loading large files. But when I put it into the script, then I need to use `from PIL import ImageFile...`. How weird, why have different behaviour between the REPL and interactive scripts?

Comment: I'm somewhat shocked this old solution is still needed and not considered by default in PIL/Pillow. Anyway, thank you! Many thumbs up for this (I actually had to use `imageio` to get a similar error that lead to this post, because Pillow simply reported an invalid action between a `JpegImageFile` and `float`).

Comment: How can I crop the grey truncated part?

Comment: came here while using Pytorch `torch.utils.data.DataLoader` for training on a image dataset - this soln works

Answer (score 18):

Here is what I did:

- Edit `LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = False` line from `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py:40` to `LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True`.

Editing the file requires root access though.
I encountered this error while running some pytorch which was maybe using the PIL library.

Do this fix only if you encounter this error, without directly using PIL.

Else please do

```
from PIL import ImageFile
ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True
```

Answer (score 13):

Best thing is that you can:

```
if img and img.meta_type == 'Image':
    pilImg = PIL.Image.open( StringIO(str(img.data)) )
elif imgData:
    pilImg = PIL.Image.open( StringIO(imgData) )

try:
    pilImg.load()
except IOError:
    pass # You can always log it to logger

pilImg.thumbnail((width, height), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

As dumb as it seems - it will work like a miracle. If your image has missing data, it will be filled with gray (check the bottom of your image).

Note: usage of camel case in Python is discouraged and is used only in class names.

Comment: I can't verify if it works, the problem disappeared miraculously. But thanks anyway :)
I used mixed case here (class names are capitalized), but that's not really encouraged either...

Answer (score 6):

This might not be a PIL issue. It might be related to your HTTP Server setting. HTTP servers put a limit on the size of the entity body that will be accepted.

For eg, in Apache FCGI, the option FcgidMaxRequestLen determines the maximum size of file that can be uploaded.

Check that for your server - it might be the one that is limiting the upload size.

Comment: Good point, but it's definitely not an HTTP issue. In the first part of my condition I access a Zope object's data. There is no HTTP-request involved and the data are ok.

Comment: Feroze is right - it is caused by trimming data on some point in data flow chain. One frequent cause is not flushing output when piping (via "|" in a shell) output of one command to input of other. It could seem to work (no direct errors) but trimmed data is produced. If you have average of 255 bytes trimmed (expected encountering of \n), then most probably it's the cause. It may also have different average, depending on file type and it's content's regularity of bytes (= inspect it anyway ;]).

Answer (score 3):

I was trapped with the same problem. However, setting `ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True` is not suitable in my case, and I have checked that all my image files were unbroken, but big.

I read the images using `cv2`, and then converted it to `PIL.Image` to get round the problem.

```py
img = cv2.imread(imgfile, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
img = Image.fromarray(img)
```

Answer (score 1):

When image was partly broken, OSError will be caused.

I use below code for check and save the wrong image list.

```
try:
    img = Image.open(file_path)
    img.load()

    ## do the work with the loaded image

except OSError as error:
    print(f"{error} ({file_path})")
    
    with open("./error_file_list.txt", "a") as error_log:
        log.write(str(file_path))
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the tds version to 7.2 to prevent this from happening.  Also works with tds version 8.0, however I had some other issues with 8.0.