# Keras giving OSError: image file is truncated (26 bytes not processed)

Tags: image, keras

I trying to classify images with 3 labels. Training samples are 6000 and validation samples contain 5000 images. The batch size is 10 and number of epochs is 30.

While executing the code in keras, during the training at first epoch, the interpreter gives the following error at 599/600 step.

Below is the snippet of code:

```
model.fit_generator(
train_generator,
steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
epochs=epochs,
validation_data=validation_generator,
validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size)

model.save_weights('weights_img.h5')
model.save('model_img.h5')
```

The interpreter gives the following error:

```
599/600 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.2541 - acc:   0.9122Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site- packages\keras\utils\data_utils.py", line 555, in get
inputs = self.queue.get(block=True).get()
 File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 608, in get
raise self._value
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 119, in worker
result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
     File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-  packages\keras\utils\data_utils.py", line 392, in get_index
    return _SHARED_SEQUENCES[uid][i]
    File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-  packages\keras\preprocessing\image.py", line 800, in __getitem__
    return self._get_batches_of_transformed_samples(index_array)
    File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-     packages\keras\preprocessing\image.py", line 1148, in      _get_batches_of_transformed_samples
   interpolation=self.interpolation)
   File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-  packages\keras\preprocessing\image.py", line 355, in load_img
   img = img.convert('RGB')
   File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 877, in convert
 self.load()
   File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFile.py", line  233, in load
  "(%d bytes not processed)" % len(b))
   OSError: image file is truncated (26 bytes not processed)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File ".\dataset.py", line 80, in <module>
validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size)
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site- packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py", line 1256, in fit_generator
initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)
 File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 2195, in fit_generator
workers=0)
 File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-  packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 2310, in evaluate_generator
generator_output = next(output_generator)
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\data_utils.py", line 561, in get
six.raise_from(StopIteration(e), e)
File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
StopIteration: image file is truncated (26 bytes not processed)
```

Comment: second answer from:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12984426/python-pil-ioerror-image-file-truncated-with-big-images

Comment: [First answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23575424/51280) worked for me.