# OSError: image file is truncated

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

When I am processing a bunch of images, on one of them I get this error

```
File "/home/tensorflowpython/firstmodel/yololoss.py", line 153, in data_generator
    image, box = get_random_data(annotation_lines[i], input_shape, random=True)
  File "/home/tensorflowpython/firstmodel/yololoss.py", line 226, in get_random_data
    image = image.resize((nw,nh), Image.BICUBIC)
  File "/home/tensorflowpython/kenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1858, in resize
    self.load()
  File "/home/tensorflowpython/kenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 247, in load
    "(%d bytes not processed)" % len(b)
OSError: image file is truncated (25 bytes not processed)
```

I have already tried the solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12984426/python-pil-ioerror-image-file-truncated-with-big-images) but it doesn't work

my code looks like this

```
from PIL import Image

def get_random_data(annotation_line, input_shape, random=True, max_boxes=20, jitter=.3, hue=.1, sat=1.5, val=1.5, proc_img=True):
    Image.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True    
    line = annotation_line.split()
    image = Image.open(line[0])
    iw, ih = image.size
    h, w = input_shape
    box = np.array([np.array(list(map(int,box.split(',')))) for box in line[1:]])
    try:
       image.load()
    except IOError:
        pass # You can always log it to logger
    if not random:
        # resize image
        scale = min(w/iw, h/ih)
        nw = int(iw*scale)
        nh = int(ih*scale)
        dx = (w-nw)//2
        dy = (h-nh)//2
        image_data=0
        if proc_img:
            image = image.resize((nw,nh), Image.BICUBIC)
            new_image = Image.new('RGB', (w,h), (128,128,128))
            new_image.paste(image, (dx, dy))
            image_data = np.array(new_image)/255.

        # correct boxes
        box_data = np.zeros((max_boxes,5))
        if len(box)>0:
            np.random.shuffle(box)
            if len(box)>max_boxes: box = box[:max_boxes]
            box[:, [0,2]] = box[:, [0,2]]*scale + dx
            box[:, [1,3]] = box[:, [1,3]]*scale + dy
            box_data[:len(box)] = box

        return image_data, box_data

    # resize image
    new_ar = w/h * rand(1-jitter,1+jitter)/rand(1-jitter,1+jitter)
    scale = rand(.25, 2)
    if new_ar < 1:
        nh = int(scale*h)
        nw = int(nh*new_ar)
    else:
        nw = int(scale*w)
        nh = int(nw/new_ar)

    image = image.resize((nw,nh), Image.BICUBIC) #error occurs here
```

The difference between  my error and the previous solution is, mine says  OS error and the solution is for IO error

EDIT: I have figured out the image that is causing this error, it can be downloaded from this [link](https://github.com/experiencor/kangaroo/blob/master/images/00090.jpg)

Comment: (Apologies for the edits – I got the impression that it was a one-off error for a single damaged image only, but you are trying to load it anyway *by adjusting your code*.)

Answer (score 12):

I tried the solution that you linked with the truncated image and it worked. You made a slight mistake when trying to apply this solution: you have to set `ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES=True`, not `Image.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES`.

`LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES` does not originally exist in `Image` module, so when you do `Image.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES=True` you set a new variable which is not used by the library.

So I think you juste have to do that:

```
from PIL import ImageFile, Image
ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True

image = Image.open("00090.jpg")
# resize now doesn't fail
image.resize((h, w), Image.BICUBIC)
```

Comment: Let me check, I was only  importing Image and not ImageFile, let me try replacing it, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: The code is depending on lot of other methods from Image class, I have to find a way to solve this by using Image, instead of ImageFile. For time being I have excluded the image which causes the error

Comment: You can still use your code with that. I'm going to update my answer with what I tried.