# Try/Except Issue and Image Corruption

Tags: python, corruption

I'm try to test images to see if any are corrupt. They all come back false, corrupted, but I know most or all are fine. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

```
import glob
from PIL import Image
import os

directory = r'C:\Users\Jim Schmitz\Documents\Pyro\dogs-vs-cats\train\dogs'
os.chdir(directory)

images=glob.glob("*.jpg")

def verify_image(img_file):
    try:
        img = Image.open(img_file)
    except:
        return False
    return True
    
for image in images:
    bool = verify_image('image')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing the string `'image'` as opposed to the filename `image`, your call should be `verify_image(image)`. Also, `bool` is a built-in python object, try to refrain from using them as variable names.

Comment: Worked on 1 folder. Another folder gave this warning:     UserWarning: Truncated File Read
  warnings.warn(str(msg)).                   File path and names don't seem longer. Ideas on this?

Comment: Ah, it means truncated in terms of the file data and not the filename, this could happen with image files even if they're valid. See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12984426/pil-ioerror-image-file-truncated-with-big-images) for an example on how to ignore it. Seems that this is all you need to add:
    `from PIL import ImageFile` and

    `ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True`