# Pillow raise OSError when fail to read image (not real OSError), how to workaround this?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Some images pass the `image.verify()` method but still fail to be read and the following errors can be raised :

```
OSError
broken data stream when reading image file
```

```
OSError
image file is truncated (XXX bytes not processed)
```

I've read many issues on github on the problem with raising OSError which does not make it possible to know whether the error comes from the image (bad format) or really from the OS (hardware problem, filesystem, full disk, etc.) :

- https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/1643
- https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/7489
- https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/7425

Since the problem is present since many years and will not be resolved soon, I ask myself how other handle this.
So here my question :

How can we disambiguate OSError raised by Pillow to determine if this is a real OS error or a file parsing/reading error from the library (because of malformatted file but still passing the `.verify` check) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PIL "IOError: image file truncated" with big images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12984426/pil-ioerror-image-file-truncated-with-big-images)

Comment: Interesting, I don't know about the `LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES` flag. I'm not sure about what I expose my app by enabling it. The Pillow documentation doesn't say much about this.